# bold specific string that is enclosed inside squeare brackets using javascript

Tags: javascript, string, bold

Hi Javascript developers i am facing an issue about bold the string that is enclosed inside of square brackets.
I have a string that is dynamically generated and the string look like

[Number] years of practice in accounting and financial administration. Showcased skills in [Area of Expertise]

I want to bold every letter inside a string that is enclosed inside the square bracket just like the above string ( [Number], [Area of Expertise] ).

Like Number and Area of Expertise must be bold.
Remember that the string is dynamic.

Comment: Maybe worth of nothing, but strings don't have a specific bold format (unless you want to mess with unicode characters). Where is this string shown? On a HTML element (which, there are different cases)? In the console? Somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Please see below snippet.

Also, it's a good idea to html-escape the string before doing the replacement, and generally before inserting dynamic content into the DOM ([read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Safely_inserting_external_content_into_a_page)).

```js
const s = '[Number] years of practice in accounting and financial administration. Showcased skills in [Area of Expertise]';

const html = s.replace(/\[([^\]]+)\]+/g, '<b>$1</b>');

console.log(html);

// => <b>Number</b> years of practice in accounting and financial administration. Showcased skills in <b>Area of Expertise</b>
```